# Update input on other input change - react

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple form with 3 inputs: a select for package selection and 2 number inputs for attendees and price and i'm trying to calculate price and attendees based on package infos but the attendees and price input doesn't update

```
<Select
  value={this.state.event.pakage.id}
  onChange = {handlePackageChange}
  inputProps={{
    name: 'evt-pkg',
    id: 'evt-pkg',
  }}>
      {this.state.pkg.map((val, key) => <MenuItem key={key} value={val.id}>{val.name}</MenuItem>)}
</Select>

const handlePackageChange = (event,newValue) => {
  let pakage = this.state.pkg.find(p => p.id === event.target.value);
  let attendees = pakage.attendees;
  let price = pakage.price * attendees;

  this.setState(prevState => ({event : {...prevState.event, pakage : {id :newVal}, attendees : attendees, price: price}}))
}
```

and the price input

```
<TextField
  id="evt-price"
  type="number"
  name="evt-price"
  onChange = {(event,newValue) => {
  var newVal = event.target.value;
  this.setState(prevState => ({event : {...prevState.event, price : newVal}}))
/>

.... attendee input
```

I see in console that the event object is updated but the input value doesn't change

Comment: you didn't assign the value to the TextField component. Try value={this.state.price}

Comment: pfff ... I tried with the defaultValue prop instead of value. It;s working, thanks

Comment: you shouldn't use defaultValue for controlled input fields.